# postgres + json object to array

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, postgresql-json

I would like to know if is possible to 'covnert' a json object to a json array to iterate over a mixed set of data.

I have two rows that look like

```
{Data:{BASE:{B1:0,color:green}}}
{Data:{BASE:[{B1:1,color:red},{B1:0,color:blue}]}}
```

I would like to extract the B1 val from all this rows, but I am a bit blocked :)

My first try was a json_extract_array, but it fails on the 1st row (not an array).
Then my second try was a json_array_length with a case, but that fails at the 1st row (not array)

Can I handle this situation in any way?
Basically I need to extract all the rows where B1 > 0 in one of the json array (or object) and maybe return the node that contains B1 > 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main problem is you mix the data types under the `json -> 'Data' -> 'BASE'` path, which cannot be handled easily. I could come up with a solution, but you should fix your schema, f.ex. to only contain arrays at that path.

```
with v(j) as (
  values (json '{"Data":{"BASE":{"B1":0,"color":"green"}}}'),
         ('{"Data":{"BASE":[{"B1":1,"color":"red"},{"B1":0,"color":"blue"}]}}')
)
select j, node
from v,
lateral (select j #> '{Data,BASE}') b(b),
lateral (select substring(trim(leading E'\x20\x09\x0A\x0D' from b::text) from 1 for 1)) l(l),
lateral (select case
  when l = '{' and (b #>> '{B1}')::numeric > 0 then b
  when l = '[' then (select e from json_array_elements(b) e where (e #>> '{B1}')::numeric > 0 limit 1)
  else null
end) node(node)
where node is not null
```

[<kbd>SQLFiddle</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/2481)

Comment: Only a good programmer could have written this code. But IMO it is way too smart/hacky. If a dumb programmer (like me?) can't write code to extract data from a certain schema then that schema is wrong.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto I agree, fixing the schema is the priority here, but i'm afraid that requires even more smart/hacky ways to do it in SQL (if it can be done at all).

Comment: the main problem here is that i can't change how the data get stored. All this data are generated by a 'tostring' of a wrapper (in java) that consist of a macro object, with a linkedlist. if the linkedlist contains 1 element, the data are serialized as jsonobject, if the linkedlist contains > 1 object, then the data are seralized as a json array.  The main reason for this 'hack' is that hte code use a tons of (for e : element.getElement("Bau")) and doesn't know if Base is an object or whatever. The only solution will be serialize everything as an array, but will be to hard to fix everything :(

Comment: seems that my best otpion is to fetch a subset of data and then filter the json on java side probably?

Comment: @user3804873 yes, fixing it on java side would be the best solution.

Comment: I agree with Clodoaldo -- that is impressive but beyond mere mortals like me. +1

Answer (score 1):

To return the rows where at least one object has `B1 > 0`

```
select *
from t
where true in (
    select (j ->> 'B1')::int > 0
    from json_array_elements (json_column -> 'Data' -> 'BASE') s (j)
)
```

Comment: This will only work, when all rows contains an array at `json_column -> 'Data' -> 'BASE'` -- otherwise throws this exception: *cannot call json_array_elements on a non-array*

Comment: @pozs That is true and I will try to fix it but I think there should be consistency in the data, I mean, there should always be an array even an empty one.

Comment: Agreed, but sadly an appropriate `UPDATE` for this (in pure SQL) is not so easy.

Comment: @posz And also sadly my query is not easily fixable. But I will keep it just to show how bad is JSON for data integrity.

Comment: if i want to get multiple records means how i have to write the query?

may be like this :

                             `select count(*) from articles where 'true in (select (j ->>   'id')::int[] ?| array['1','2'] from json_array_elements (json::json -> 'category_ids') s (j))`

Comment: This Query is working as expected:
`select id from articles where 'True'='True'  in (select (j ->> 'id')::int in (60,53,333) from json_array_elements (json::json -> 'category_ids') s (j));`

Answer (score 0):

With a little help from the other answers here, I did this:

```
with v(j) as (
  values (json '{"Data":{"BASE":{"B1":0,"color":"green"}}}'),
         ('{"Data":{"BASE":[{"B1":1,"color":"red"},{"B1":0,"color":"blue"}]}}')
)
select j->'Data'->'BASE'->>'B1' as "B1"
from v 
where j->'Data'->'BASE'->>'B1' is not null
union all
select json_array_elements(j->'Data'->'BASE')->>'B1'
from v
where j->'Data'->'BASE'->>'B1' is null
```

Divided it into two queries, one which just fetches a single value if there is only one, and one that unwraps the array if there are multiple, utilizing that PostgreSQL returns `null` if you ask for the text of something that is an array. Then, I just unioned the result from the two queries, which resulted in:

```
 ------
|  B1  |
 ------
|  0   |
|  1   |
|  0   |
```